# Arquillian Suite Extension - Should we add all test classes in Suite

Tags: jboss-arquillian

When using Arquillian Suite Extension , should we add the other test classes using ShrinkWrap or Arquillian should do that.

Currently I am trying to use Arquillian Suite, it is adding only the class with @Runwith and rest all classes using same deployment are not added and class not found exception is generated

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mention for which class `ClassNotFoundException` is being thrown. So please update your original question.

btw. it seems that you simply missed some classes in your `@Deployment` method. Consider usage of **addPackages** method to add all relevant classes at once.

```
@Deployment
public static JavaArchive createDeployment() {
    JavaArchive jar = ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class)
            .addPackages(true, "my.package")
            .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");

    return jar;
}
```

Comment: thank you Grzeseik for replying. Apart from that I had testable = false, in that case test cases are not executed in the container itself, but they are external to container. So adding just @Deployment, (because bydefault testable=true) solved my prolem